# Cauchy sequence in metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Give an example of a metric space such that a Cauchy sequence in $M$ that is not convergent. How can we give a example of that?

Answer (score 2):

$\Bbb Q$ with the usual distance, and the sequence $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

$(0,1)$ with the Euclidean metric (i.e. the usual metric).

The sequence $<\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}>$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(0,1)$, but has no limit in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Try
$$\frac{\lfloor N\sqrt{2}\rfloor}{N}$$
in $\mathbb{Q}$ as $N\to \infty$. This converges to $\sqrt{2}$, which is not in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: +1. Forgive my denseness, but is it easy to prove that this is a Cauchy sequence? Intuitively, it is obvious what is happening, but it seems a bit ugly to prove. Perhaps that is a silly thing to get hung up on, though. :)

Comment: @AWertheim It is Cauchy because it converges to $\sqrt 2$. Indeed, the $N$th term differs by less than $\frac1N$ from the limit, and hence by less than $\frac2N$ from any later term.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $x_n = 1/n$, in the space $]0,1]$ with the usual metric induced by $|\cdot|$. The point to which the sequence would go, $0$, isn't in the space.